# checklist not getting value django form

Tags: django, django-forms

When I try to edit info on my table. Everything works perfectly except for the fact that my checklist does not get value. All other fields get value when the edit modal is loaded. Note that when I tried getting value on a separate page instead of a modal it still did not work. I have cut my code to make it more readable. If you want to see more please let me know. Here is my code.

forms.py:

```
class TraineeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
                        ('Male', 'Male'),
                      ('Female', 'Female'),
                      ('Other', 'Other')
                      ]
    EDUCATION_CHOICES = [
        ('P', 'Primary'),
        ('J', 'Junior'),
        ('S', 'Senior')

    ]

    TraineePic = forms.ImageField(label="Image :", required=False, widget=forms.ClearableFileInput())

    Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), label='Name :')
    Course = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}),choices=course_choices, label='Course :')
    BatchNo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4', 'placeholder':'Numbers only'}), label='Batch No :')
    Gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-4 form-check-inline', 'id':'id_Gender'}),label='Gender :', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    Education = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'col-sm-4 form-check-inline','id':'id_Education'}), label='Education :', choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)

    class Meta():
        model = Trainee
        fields = ("Name","Course","BatchNo","Gender","Education",)
```

views.py:

```
def updateTrainee(request, id):
    trainee = get_object_or_404(Trainee, pk=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TraineeForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=trainee)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(status=204,  headers={'HX-Trigger' : 'changeDetected'})
    else:
        form = TraineeForm(instance=trainee)

    return render(request, 'MyTestApp/save.html', {'form':form})
```

save/edit.html:

```
<form class="modal-content" enctype="multipart/form-data" hx-post="{{request.path}}" autocomplete="off" >
      {%csrf_token%}


        <div class="modal-header">
            {% if trainee %}
                <h5 class="modal-title"> Edit a Trainee </h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add a Trainee </h5>

            <button class="close" type="button" id="span_close_modal_btn"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span>
            </button>
            {%endif%}
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Name: </label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            {{form.Name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Gender: </label>
                        <div class="col-8" id="gender_div_id" >
                            {{form.Gender}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row" >
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Education: </label>
                        <div class="col-8" >
                            {{form.Education}}
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="Course"> Course: </label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            {{form.Course}}

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> BatchNo: </label>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            {{form.BatchNo}}
                        </div>
                    </div>.............
```

models.py

```
class Trainee(models.Model):
TraineeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Course = models.CharField(max_length=40)
BatchNo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
Gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Education = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Meta():
    db_table = "Trainee"
```

[image: Here it is on the modal]
[image: Here it is on the actual page. I am injecting the page into the modal.]

Comment: please add model in code

Comment: Have added models.py  
@Mahammadhusain kadiwala

Comment: plz check it answer added....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its directly not possible in django but you can achieve it using third party library for more info open link  [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/)

i alredy archive that like this

### ---- models.py --------

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
EDUCATION_CHOICES = [('P', 'Primary'),('J', 'Junior'),('S', 'Senior')]
class Trainee(models.Model):
    TraineeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    BatchNo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Education = MultiSelectField(choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES)
```

### ---- form.py --------

```
class TraineeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trainee
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
        'Education':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }
```

### ----- output in admin pannel -------

[image]

[image]

### ---- in html page ------

[image]

Comment: its not working

Comment: My side working fine plz check your code as per my code
I also puted screen shots

Comment: Please check my code again

Comment: If still not working please update in question your changes

Comment: nvm man its working but how do I add html attributes now

Comment: updated in answer in form.py check it